# Java: Comparing two Bufferedimages using loops

Tags: java, image, compare

When i want to check if two Bufferedimages are the same, i can simply compare them pixel by pixel using these two loops:

```
boolean bufferedImagesEqual(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
if (img1.getWidth() == img2.getWidth() && img1.getHeight() == img2.getHeight()) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(x, y))
                return false;
        }
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I took this from  : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305037/java-compare-one-bufferedimage-to-another)

But I also want this to work if `img2` is rotated by `90 or 270` degrees. I tried swtiching `x` and `y` , using combinations like 
    `img2.getWidth()-x` 
in the second `.getRGB()` but none of it seems to work.

I know it may not be the hardest problem in the world but i cannot seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is unavoidable to perform the "2-loops" 3 times: 
one for 0 degree rotation, the second 90 and the third 270:

For 90 degrees: (assert img1.getWidth()==img2.getHeight() && img1.getHeight()==img2.getWidth())

```
for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
        if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(img1.getHeight() - 1 - y, x))
            return false;
    }
}
```

For 270 degrees: (assert img1.getWidth()==img2.getHeight() && img1.getHeight()==img2.getWidth())

```
for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
        if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(y, img1.getWidth() - 1 - x))
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but i'm getting out-of-bounds errors in the 90-degree loops and false results in the 270-loops. Am i missing something ?

Comment: No it is me who missed something. I know what the problem is, I will fix it now

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again ,but did you fix it yet ?

Comment: You are most welcome. I would really appreciate if you could vote me up. Good luck :)