# Is there any way to compare two RenderedImage in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, pdfbox

I have a list of RenderedImage "List imagesList", now I wanna check whether two objects from the above list are same or not. I tried with comparing two file but not with the list of RenderedImages. Does anyone have any idea how to compare RenderedImage? Do I have to use any library to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing"? Like checking their pixels have the same colour? They are the same RenderedImage object?

Comment: I know `imagemagick` has variety of options, it may help you. But not sure it has any feature for comparison, check more http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd compare those two objects pixel by pixel. I'm sure it's slow, but I'm sure too it should work.

Related: [Java Compare one BufferedImage to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305092/3696685)

Comment: Yup. That's really the only option you have. +1

Comment: Thanks captainepoch. I converted RenderedImage to BufferedImage and used your code and it worked.

Comment: @PramodNikule I'm happy it worked. It's not my code, credit goes to the authors.

Comment: Coincidentally, that's also what is done in PDFBox as part of rendering quality testing: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/test/java/org/apache/pdfbox/rendering/TestPDFToImage.java?view=markup (test is disabled in standard build, it is done locally by PDFBox developers due to differences depending of the OS and installed fonts)